# pyinstaller fails to find QtOpenGl for QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView (used to display PDFs)

Tags: pycharm, pyinstaller, qtopengl

My code is running fine in Pycharm. It properly displays PDFs.  When I make the pyinstaller version, it will fail and give this message 'Library not loaded: @rpath/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/A/QtOpenGL'. I use pyinstaller from my non-virtual environment where all the same modules as I have in Pycharm are installed.  First time I have had a problem. Also, I noticed the application file size ballooned from about 158K to 840K when I included the QtWebEngineWidget module. I see that QtOpenGL exists in 'site-packages/PySide6/Qt/lib/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/A' (where I think it should be?). What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing this answer, the `develop` branch of pyinstaller works for me.

See the merged PR at https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/6892 for more info.

Comment: This is the first comment I have posted on stackoverflow.com.  Gabe, thanks for for your response to my question.  I downloaded pyinstaller v5.2 and my OpenGL problem disappeared so I assume the most recent release had the fixes for my problem.